# Add select option with other select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use `<select id="dropdown_for_add">`  to add the list in the `<select id="mySelect">`

If I choose the "Add Item" option,  it will add option in  `<select id="mySelect">`

The problem is

- after add item, if I choose other option of `<select id="dropdown_for_add">` (A, B, C option ), I want to remove the recently add item of `<select id="mySelect">`
- How to add more than 2 option at once? Now I can add only one item to `<select id="mySelect">`

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("dropdown_for_add").value == 2) {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Item1";
    x.add(option);
    option.text = "Item2";
    x.add(option);
  }

}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>

  <select id="dropdown_for_add" onchange="myFunction()">

    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">Add item</option>
    <option value="3">B</option>
    <option value="4">C</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
```

Comment: Why don't u use hide ? if add option is select then u show 2 more if not hide those elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. As `option` refers to same DOM element you can't append it twice, Simplest solution is to create another `option`.

```
 var option2 = document.createElement("option");
 option2.text = "Item2";
 x.add(option2);
```

To remove options you have iterate

```
if (document.getElementById("dropdown_for_add").value == 2) {
    ...
} else {
    for (var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (x.options[i].value == 'Item1' || x.options[i].value == 'Item2') {
            x.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  if (document.getElementById("dropdown_for_add").value == 2) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Item1";
    x.add(option);
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option2.text = "Item2";
    x.add(option2);
  } else {
    for (var i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (x.options[i].value == 'Item1' || x.options[i].value == 'Item2') {
        x.remove(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown_for_add" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">Add item</option>
  <option value="3">B</option>
  <option value="4">C</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

---

Other options is to use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```
 var option2 = option.cloneNode();
 option2.text = "Item2";
 x.add(option2);
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  if (document.getElementById("dropdown_for_add").value == 2) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Item1";
    x.add(option);
    var option2 = option.cloneNode();
    option2.text = "Item2";
    x.add(option2);
  } else {
    for (var i = x.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (x.options[i].value == 'Item1' || x.options[i].value == 'Item2') {
        x.remove(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown_for_add" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">Add item</option>
  <option value="3">B</option>
  <option value="4">C</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```

Comment: after add option, can you remove the addded option, if choose A,B,C option?

Comment: Sorry I mean, remove all 2 item :) at once

Comment: @doflamingo, please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use [Select add() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp). Then you have to use [remove](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_remove.asp) method in order to `remove` added `elements`.

```js
function myFunction() {
   if (document.getElementById("dropdown_for_add").value == 2) {
     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
     var option = document.createElement("option");
      x.add(new Option('Item1',"Item1"));
      x.add(new Option('Item2',"Item2"));
   }
   else{
      
       var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
       if(x[x.length-1].text=="Item2"){
          x.remove(x.length-1);
          x.remove(x.length-1);
       }
   }
 }
```

```html
<select id="dropdown_for_add" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">Add item</option>
  <option value="3">B</option>
  <option value="4">C</option>
</select>

<select id="mySelect">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>
```